# Make foreground control transparent for click/tap like iOS's disabled user interaction

Tags: android, user-interface

In iOS controls has a property "`User Interaction`" which could be enabled or not. When it is disabled the control is visible to the user but it is not interactive. So any tap/click etc receives the nearest control behind this not interactive control.
So the question is what is the same android's property? Is it `focusable`?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such property on Android. If you want user to wait untill sime long procedure ends, just use ProgressDialog with `setCancelable(true)` - it will overlay your Activity and allows pretty none interaction. Hide the dialog when the job is done.

Comment: You didn't understand the point of a question, its not about locking UI for something. I need to be able to click through some control. Imagine an image is placed foreground and a button behind it. Now I need to make image transparent for my clicks so the button has to receive all my clicks instead of image.